# Gerando Pagina HTML por PHP a partir da base de dados

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Estou aprendendo php com mysql e utilizo wamp.

Estou desenvolvendo um site à termos somente acadêmicos, e estou com um problema:
Tenho uma base de dados com 20 pilotos, e cada piloto tem informações como idade, descrição,altura, eu estava querendo usar PHP pra fazer uma página de modelo, e para cada piloto eu pudesse usar suas informações, e o programa PHP iria mudar as informações de acordo com um menu pré-estabelecido, sem a necessidade de que eu tivesse ter que fazer 20 paginas para cada piloto, e assim o programa PHP selecionasse os dados da base de dados...

Alguém tem alguma fonte de onde posso encontrar bases para isso, soluções semelhantes, códigos, e bibliografias que me ajudem a desenvolver minhas habilidades em PHP...

Comment: gostaria de acessa os dados por ID, e cada item seria um link,que redicionaria a sua pagina...

Comment: Existem várias formas de implementar isso... você já tem algum código pra que possamos dar uma olhada e trabalhar em cima dele?

Comment: entao Ricardo BRGWeb, eu tenho ja o codigo do meu site e a pagina de modelo, mas a unica coisa que falta é chamar os dados correspondente na hora que a pessoa selecionar o link, basicamente o que me falta é essa ligacao entre a base de dados e o PHP que quero fazer pra a base de dados

Comment: Coloca o código da sua página na pergunta e o formato das colunas do banco de dados... a melhor forma de fazer isso, inclusive como aprendizado, é usando PHP orientado a objeto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, vou te passar um exemplo de como mais ou menos eu faria, não se preocupe com funções que não conhece, e logo aproveitando, quando for perguntar aqui tenha logo um código meio pronto, isso facilitará as pessoas a te ajudar.
Mas vamos pro exemplo:

*sistema.php:*

```
//Constantes da conexão
define("DB_HOST","localhost");
define("DB_NAME","root");
define("DB_USER","exemplo");
define("DB_PASS","123");

//Criamos uma classe pra o sistema
class sistema
{
  //Definimos o método private para o $db_connection
  private $db_connection = null;

  //Criaremos uma conexão com o banco de dados, usando PDO
  private function databaseConnection()
        {
        // Conexao berta
        if ($this->db_connection != null)
            {
            return true;
            }
        else
            {
            // Criando a conexao com banco de dados, usando constantes
            try
                {
                $this->db_connection = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
                return true;
                // Tratamento de erro, caso falhe a conexao
                }
            catch (PDOException $e)
                {
                $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_DATABASE_ERROR;
                return false;
                }
            }
        }


//Criar função que acessa o sua tabela
public function buscarPilotos($nome_piloto)
{
  //Chamamos a conexão com o banco
  $this->databaseConnection();

  //Selecionaremos a tabela com o nome do piloto passado pela função, faremos uso de Prepared statements para uma melhor segurança
  $pilotos = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM pilotos WHERE nome_piloto = :nomedopiloto');

  //Usaremos o bindValue para passar o nome do piloto à conexão
  $pilotos->bindValue(':nomedopiloto', $nome_piloto, PDO::PARAM_STR);

  //Executar a ação para nos retornar a query
  $pilotos->execute();

  //Vamos usar o fetchAll para nos retornar uma array com os dados do piloto
  $piloto_encontrados = $pilotos->fetchAll();

  //Vamos usar a Foreach para nos listar este piloto num formato HTML, usando divs html (pode ser tabelas ou o que quiser, vou só ilustrar) 

  foreach($piloto_encontrados as $pilot)
  {
    echo '<div id="nomedopiloto">'.$pilot["nome"].'</div>
  <div id="idadedopiloto">'.$pilot["idade"].'</div>
  <div id="alturadopiloto">'.$pilot["altura"].'</div>';
  }
}


}
```

Pronto, criado o arquivo do sistema, iremos para o arquivo principal, onde esperamos ter as `divs` já com seus estilos `css` e etc.

*index.php*

```
<?php
//Vamos incluir nosso arquivo de sistema
require("sistema.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/estilo.css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Exemplo PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="piloto">
<?php 
//Vamos iniciar nossa classe
$pegar_piloto = new sistema();
//Vamos passar o nome do piloto para a função
$pegar_piloto->buscarPilotos("Cassiano");
//Irá imprimir os resultados
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Observe: isto que fiz foi apenas para ***EXEMPLO***, até por que estou meio ocupado, existe muitas técnicas para inserir dados em `HTML` vindo de `BD`, usando por exemplo o bom padrão `MVC`, fazendo-se uso do projeto [Dwoo](http://dwoo.org/) e etc.
Mas como você é iniciante, eu fiz isso apenas para você se perguntar; "O que é isso?, o que é aquilo?" e buscar isto por aí em fóruns e etc, pois a melhor forma de aprender é se perguntando, buscando, e com certeza aprenda logo o melhor que o `PHP` oferece, a Orientação a Objetos.

Boa sorte!

Comment: poooww, cara, muito obrigado mesmo, vai ajudar muito!!

Comment: A Disposição ;)